# jQuery selector last element of of next sibling

Tags: jquery, html

I recently had to write code to search a page for the value of a field associated with a title.  The HTML structure is in the following form:

```html
    <table><tr>
    ...etc...
    <td><div><span>Type of Fruit:</span></div></td>
    <td><span><div><span><div>Orange</div></span></div></span></td>
    ...etc...
    </tr></table>
```

I solved the problem with the following jQuery:

```js
    var strFruitType = $('span').filter(function(){ 
          return $(this).text() === 'Type of Fruit:';
    }).closest('td').next().find(':last').text().trim();

    //Evaluate Fruit Type.
    switch(strFruitType) {
    ...etc...
```

Is this the most straightforward or efficient way to locate the last element of the next sibling of something?

Comment: Do you have control over the HTML?

Comment: No, I have no control over the HTML.  My task is to determine the value associated with the title "Type of Fruit:" (obviously, not the real title or data) and act on it.  There are other title/value combinations on the page that I may need to evaluate as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have no control of the HTML, what you have looks pretty good. Just a couple of things:

If searching for a string that *contains* "Type of Fruit:" is OK, you could do:

```
$('span:contains("Type of Fruit:")').closest('td').next().find(':last').text().trim();
```

Which you may even be able to shorten to:

```
$('td:contains("Type of Fruit:")').next().find(':last').text().trim();
```

Also, I'm not sure how simplified your example is, but it looks like you may be using `:last` to find the *deepest* element in the sibling `td` element. But `:last` really finds the last direct child. So if your `td` could have more than one direct child like this:

```
<td>
    <span><div><span><div>Orange</div></span></div></span>
    <span><div><span><div>Apple</div></span></div></span>
</td>
```

You'd end up with "Apple", but it's because `:last` found the second `span` directly inside the `td`. So if your `td` will only ever have one direct child, then you don't need `:last`.

This leaves us with:

```
$('td:contains("Type of Fruit:")').next().text().trim();
```